# JSON Parsing Error when connection android device to SqlServer 2005

Tags: php, android, json, sql-server-2005

I have done the following tutorial:
http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/connecting-to-mysql-database-t50063.html
for connecting an android device to an sqlserver(2005) using php. I have checked my php script and it runs and executes fine. When I run my program I get the following error:

```
01-26 14:17:43.491: E/log_tag(331): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-27 09:24:13.610: E/log_tag(404): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-27 09:26:45.190: E/log_tag(437): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-27 09:31:14.221: E/log_tag(471): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-27 09:43:44.501: E/log_tag(504): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I want my program to connect to the database and return the names of everyone whose EngineerId is greater than zero. Here is my code:

```
package com.david.DbConnect;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DbConnectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources 
    // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML. 
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); 
    txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); 
    rootLayout.addView(txt); 
    setContentView(rootLayout); 

    // Set the text and call the connect function. 
    txt.setText("Connecting...");
  //call the method to run the data retreival
    txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121));



}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/dbconnect.php"; //i use my real ip here



private String getServerData(String returnString) {

   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EngID","0"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
           // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","ContactName: "+json_data.getInt("ContactName")
                    );
                    //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return returnString;
}   

}
```

Here is my php script:

```
<?php
$serverName = "xxxxxx"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxxx", "UID"=>"xxxxxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//-----------------------------------------------
// Perform operations with connection.
//-----------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT ContactName FROM dbo.TBL_FACILITY_JOB_CALLS WHERE EngineerID>'".$_REQUEST['EngID']."'" ;
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql );
if ($stmt === false) {
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row['ContactName']. "<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);



while($e=sqlsrv_fetch_assoc( $row))

              $output[]=$e;

           print(json_encode($output));

    sqlsrv_close();





?>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? It has been wrecking my head for days. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong data output by PHP. You cannot output any data except Json, so you should remove:

```
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
```

and any other echo'ed data except:

```
print(json_encode($output));
```

Additionally you should add headers for json, before send any data output:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: When I take out the echo'd data I now have a connection error:    Error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I think the data you are getting from server is not in the format of Json file. you have the exception at the line:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

1. make sure that in the result string, there must be data in json file structure.
2. extract data from json accordingly to the structure of json file.